# Add Text widget to ListView that has its children mapped in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I have a ListView that presents its children from a map dynamically. The ListView is inside an animated controller that shows and hides the ListView. How would I add one Text widget to the bottom of the ListView? Or should I use ListView.builder instead?

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: duration),
    height: _expandRedFlag ? (args.map1.length * 37.0 + 20) : 0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
    child: Container(
      child: ListView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: args.map1.entries
            .map((e) => Column(children: [
                  Row(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "${e.value}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8,
                        height: 25,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          e.key,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 2,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]))
            .toList(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a ready to use solution for this!

Use [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html)

> A scrolling container that animates items when they are inserted or removed. This widget's AnimatedListState can be used to dynamically insert or remove items. To refer to the AnimatedListState either provide a GlobalKey or use the static of method from an item's input callback. This widget is similar to one created by ListView.builder.